# Making hardware profiles for Linux installation

Tags: virtualbox, kernel, kernel-module

So, I've got a ArchLinux installation on /dev/sda11, and I've imported it into VirtualBox using raw host partitions. Right now, I can boot it both directly and through VirtualBox. The problem is the modules needed for drivers and firmwares. Is there any way to set [probably automatic] hardware profile detection, so that Linux would load different kernel modules (e.g. intel and related stuff for direct boot, and vbox things for VirtualBox)

Comment: Your distribution may be relevant. On Gentoo, you could do something like this with [softlevels](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=4).